# Search data by the beginning of the word for only one column

Tags: datatables

I have a column named State having two states: "active" and "inactive".
With default search, user cannot get only "active" records.
I don't want to use select (combo) or separate input fields for each column or checkbox.
When user types "ac" , table should show records having state "active" or at another column (for example, "fruit") value "peach" etc.
I have tried this so far:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
oSettings = table.fnSettings();
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ 4 ].sSearch = "^ac";
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ 4 ].bRegex = true;
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ 4 ].bSmart= false;
```

but this has a wrong effect: it will always display only active records - I need it to get the input value and search for that, also I don't want the input text to be searched only at the fourth column, but all of them.

I also tried this:

```
 regExSearch = '^ac';
 table.column(4).search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
```

Also does the same thing.

I tried fnFiter and it has the same effect.

To sum up: I need the user to be able to see all records with state "active" and fruit "peach" when he enters "ac".

Comment: It's working for you?? https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/107/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this does work but it does not solve my problem the way I wanted. I really need it to work with input box, not checkbox. I have more than one column that would need this type of search, so users would not be fine with this type of solution. Thank you anyway. If I don't find any solution that works the way I descibed, I will use youtrs.

Comment: You need find by column?https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html or https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html